# Calculating 2 rows in a table with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.1

This is my first question and I am new with Rails.
I am currently stuck with something rather simple but I am not finding my way out.
In my costs/index/html.erb file
I have the following rows:

```
<tbody>
    <% @costs.each do |cost| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= cost.mini_description %></td>
        <td><%= cost.description %></td>
        <td><%= cost.quantity %></td>
        <td><%= cost.rate %></td>
        <td><%= cost.total %></td>
        <td><%= cost.total_of_all_rows %></td>
        <td><%= cost.job %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', cost %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_cost_path(cost) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', cost, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
</tbody>
```

I am trying to calculate the rate and the quantity in order to yield the total amount. Asa a result, I have create the following variable and I have called it yet I am being thrown errors. Where have I gone wrong?:

```
<tbody>
    <% @costs.each do |cost| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= cost.mini_description %></td>
        <td><%= cost.description %></td>
        <td><%= cost.quantity %></td>
        <td><%= cost.rate %></td>
        <%= cost_var = cost.quantity * cost.rate %>
        <td><%= cost.total, cost_var %></td>
        <td><%= cost.total_of_all_rows %></td>
        <td><%= cost.job %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', cost %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_cost_path(cost) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', cost, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

*
Thank you to everyone who contributed.
In my model I put
`def cost_var
  quantity * rate
end`

In my view I called

```
<td><%= cost.total%><%=cost.cost_var%></td>
```

my issues was that my quantity and rate types when I scaffolded were strings. I had to change the by adding .to_f in my model like so:

`def cost_var
  quantity.to_f * rate.to_f
end`

And now it finally works!  Thank you to both @Iceman and @Micah

Comment: Please add the errors in the question

Comment: @kirtiThorat It is probably my own ignorance because I am getting syntax errors:  - syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '='
...append=( cost.total, cost_var );@output_buffer.safe_append='...
...                               ^
-syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
';     end 
          ^
- syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')'
- syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'

Comment: In addition to pulling calculations out of your view, `<%= cost.total, cost_var %>` is an invalid line if I'm not mistaken. are you trying to display something like the following: `50,35`? if so you need to do `<%= cost.total %>,<%= cost_var %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to deal with this is adding a method to the model

```
def quantity_rate
  quantity * rate
end
```

And then just use that in your view like the rest.

```
<%= cost.quantity_rate %>
```

Comment: @Iceman Thank you  for your help so I added the method in my model and then I included it in the view. Yet I am still getting this error :private method `quantity_rate' called for #<Cost:0x007ff52e211148>

Comment: @CodingKat You have put your method somewhere below a `private` line in your model, pull it above that line.

Comment: @Micah my model is as follows:                                   class Cost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job
end

def cost_var
  quantity * rate
end

Comment: This looks ok, but you will of course have to replace quantity_rate in your view then. @CodingKat

Comment: as @iceman said, whatever you define your function as in your model is what you need to call it in your view. However you also have an `end` in the wrong place. Directly after your `belongs_to :job` you have `end` which closes out your class, leaving `def cost_var` orphaned, or in this case private. Put that end to the very last line of your model and you should be good to go.

Comment: @Iceman pardon my ignorance but what do you mean by replacing quantity_rate in my view?

Comment: @CodingKat In my answer I have quantity_rate but in your model you had cost_var, you have to choose either one :)

Comment: @Micah so I have fixed my model:class Cost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job

def cost_var
  quantity * rate
end
  end

Comment: @Iceman I have selected cost_var and in my view this is how I am calling it yet I am still encountering errors:   <td><%= cost.total%>,<%=cost.cost_var%></td>... Thank you both for your patience

Comment: @Micah  what am I doing wrong? The error states can't convert String into Integer.

Comment: @Iceman in my view this is what I am calling: <td><%= cost.total%>,<%=cost.cost_var%></td> but now the error says:"Can't convert string into integer"

Comment: Is either quantity or rate a string?

Comment: @Iceman When I scaffolded them I did put them as a string type. So yes they are both strings.

Comment: @CodingKat Then you have to do quantity.to_f * rate.to_f and hope it works

Comment: @Iceman sorry to ask but am I making this change in the model or the view?

Comment: @CodingKat In the model

Comment: @CodingKat But it is not advisable to have numbers or currency stores as strings in the db, it is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @CodingKat Glad it worked out, but I would nevertheless think about your design a bit regarding storing numbers in strings in the db.

Comment: Sorry I disappeared, @CodingKat. Meeting at work. Glad iceman was able to help you out. As he said don't store numerical values as strings whenever possible or you'll just have a headache. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You want to avoid doing calculations in your ERB files whenever possible (read: always). Do as many of your calculations in your models as you can and whatever is left do in your controller. For this particular case I would create a method in your `Cost` model called `cost_var` like this:

```
def cost_var
  quantity * rate
end
```

then call it in the ERB file by `cost.cost_var`. This way you aren't performing calculations in your view page.

In addition to pulling calculations out of your view, `<%= cost.total, cost_var %>` is an invalid line if I'm not mistaken. are you trying to display something like the following: `50,35`? if so you need to do `<%= cost.total %>,<%= cost_var %>`